# Does the U.S. President have a red phone?

Tags: history, united-states, government

From a [2010 news article](http://www.reuters.com/article/2010/06/24/usa-russia-idUSN2413146620100624):

> Obama noted that Medvedev had opened a
> Twitter account while visiting the
> company's headquarters in California.
>
> "*I have one, as well, so we may be
> able to finally throw away **those red
> phones** that have been sitting around
> for so long*," he said to laughter,
> referring to **the Cold War-era direct
> hotline between U.S. and Kremlin
> leaders**.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow-Washington_hotline) has a picture of Jimmy Carter's "Red Phone":

[image: Jimmy Carter's phone]

But according to this [CNN article](http://web.archive.org/web/20080923200642/http://www.cnn.com/SPECIALS/cold.war/episodes/10/spotlight/):

> Contrary to popular myth and Hollywood
> portrayal, **the hot line has never been
> a pair of red telephones**, one in a
> drawer in the Oval Office, the other
> in the Kremlin.
>
> **At first it was a set
> of teletypes** with messages punched in
> at a rate of about one page every
> three minutes. That system was
> replaced in the late 1970s with two
> satellite systems, as well as an
> undersea cable link.

[Crypto Machines](http://jproc.ca/crypto/hotline_phones.html) also says:

> Many people believe that a red
> telephone was part of the
> Washington-Moscow Hotline (WMH). **There
> were NO phones at all on the hotline,
> let alone red ones.**
>
> The so-called "RED
> HOTLINE"  between Washington and
> Moscow was actually a [secure TELETYPE
> link](http://jproc.ca/crypto/hotline.html).
>
> [image: Teletype]

My question:

**Is it just a myth that the U.S. President has/had a phone that is actually red?**

If yes, what's the explanation for Jimmy Carter's red phone?

Comment: To your last question: The [bat phone](http://www.google.ca/search?q=bat+phone&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=ssx&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=1VfpTdj7NIS4sQOoyYCIDg&ved=0CD0QsAQ&biw=1229&bih=670), obviously.

Comment: @Lagerbaer: That link syntax does not work for comments. Instead, use [text](link) to hyperlink text in comments. I fixed your comment above to display like you intended.

Comment: the "phone" you show for Carter is an obvious fake. Looks like a block of wood crudely shaped into something resembling an old model telphone and painted red.

Comment: "Yeah, it's obviously wood-shopped, I can tell from the splinters." :-) I simply do not agree with @jwenting that it is obviously faked. And surely anyone going to fake it would simply get a real-live off-the-shelf phone and fake its provenance, rather than putting a wooden item on display that any visitor could "obviously" see, and could be proven in 3 seconds by picking up the receiver. (Am I missing the irony? Is there a hook in my cheek?)

Comment: If you wanted to call the Soviets, what else would you use but the Red Phone?

Comment: Well both presidents have Twitter accounts, so just ask them :)

Answer (score 17):

I did some research about the Washington-Moscow Hotline and I can also say that there was NEVER a phone on that link. People who worked at the Hotline until as late as 2008 confirm in interviews that the hotline never had a voice capability. The Hotline first used teletype equipment, since 1988 facsimile units and since 2008 the messages are exchanged by e-mail.

For more info and sources check my article: http://electrospaces.blogspot.nl/2012/10/the-washington-moscow-hot-line.html

The red phone of Jimmy Carter is not fake, but was used for a different purpose. It was most likely used as part of the Defense Red Switch Network, linking the president, the secretary of defense and all the major command centers. So not for international, but for internal use, that is the chain of command for the US defense system.

Comment: I wonder if they used emoticons to tone down the rhetoric -- "We will bury you in the ash-heap of history! ;-) "

Comment: If you put some of the relevant links of your article in your answer (so that your sources show up here directly) I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

From the very same [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow-Washington_hotline) article that you cite, the discrepancy is made clear:

> The first generation of the hot line had no voice element at all; the memorandum called for a full-time duplex wire telegraph circuit, based on the idea that spontaneous verbal communications could lead to miscommunications and misperceptions.

> In September 1971, it was decided to upgrade the system with better technology. [...] A phone was installed, and the main telegraph line was complemented by two new satellite communication lines, one formed by two US Intelsat satellites and the other composed of two Soviet Molniya II satellites. This phase of upgrade lasted from 1971–1978, and in the process the Washington-Tangier-Moscow radio line was eliminated. [...]

For reference, Jimmy Carter was president 1977–1981, overlapping the late stages of the implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure how reliable Wiki is in this case, since they also have that (fake?) picture of Jimmy Carter's phone (_according to the description it's from the "Jimmy Carter Library and Museum"_)

Comment: @Oliver_C, I don't see any inconsistency. From 1967 until 1971, NO PHONE. 1971-78, PHONE GETS INSTALLED (slowly!). 1977-1981, Carter is president, with shiny red phone.

Comment: Wiki never states that the phone was actually __red__, and the CNN article says `the hot line has never been a pair of red telephones`.